# Automatically deleting newly added files when shelving in Perforce

Tags: perforce

When I shelve a pending changelist, changes to existing files are reverted, but newly added files are not deleted from the filesystem. I need to manually delete these files every time I perform a shelve operation. Is there anyway to automatically delete newly added files when shelving?

Comment: Why is this not a feature.

Comment: @marsh It finally is!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way to do this.  This behavior is consistent with reverting files that have been added.  If you 'p4 add' a file and then revert it, it will not be deleted on revert.  Seems like it would be bad behavior if it did!  Losing a file and the work that has gone into the file on a revert would be very bad.  Consider this:  you code up a file in your editor, you save diligently, and finally you are ready to 'p4 add' it to perforce.  Then you decide you don't want to do this so you revert and then you lose your file???

So reverting adds won't delete the file.

Comment: -1 there is no data loss issue to deleting the local copy of a shelved file here. The shelved file is likely more backed up after shelving as it is stored in the p4 server. Although this is consistent with p4 revert that is unfortunatle and annoying in cases such as MusikPolice pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

in p4, if you're willing to make it two operations, you can do a normal shelve on the changelist, and then do `p4 revert -w` on the same changelist, which deletes added files.   i'm not sure how to do this in p4v.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like P4V added this in a recent release!

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/p4vnotes.txt

> #40757 (Changes #1619278, #1618572)
>       The Shelve Dialog has an option to remove the files from disk that are marked for
>       'Add'.

Answer (score 2):

To do this in p4v, you can create a custom tool, say "revert-added-file-and-delete", adding it to applicable context menus, with application p4 and arguments revert -w %F.

Unless someone knows of a way to chain custom tools together (and I couldn't find a way to do it),  to do a shelve/revert will require a separate shelve followed by a use of the custom command, revert-added-file-and-delete.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, except that shelving work is a fundamentally different beast. If I create a new class that uses a new function in an existing class, and then shelve both files, the new class remains, and is now referencing a non-existent function in the existing class. Now I've got build errors and have to manually delete the new file in order to get back to a clean slate, which is exactly what shelving work should do for me.

Comment: p4ideax is the place to vote for perforce changes, this posted idea is relevant: http://p4ideax.com/ideas/436/shelves-should-not-orphan-files-open-for-add

Answer (score 0):

1. p4 shelve -c changelist_number
2. p4 revert -w -c changelist_number //...